# How to find who created a AWS resources without Cloud Trail?

Tags: amazon-web-services

My organization asked me to list all resources currently running on AWS. We have more than 150 resources especially `RDS Snapshots` and `Lambda functions`. Most of those resources were created between 2018 and 2019. Cloud Trail was never activated.

So far I was able to get the complete list of all the resources but now how can I identify who created each resource?

Comment: do those resources have tags?

Comment: For 95% of them, none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information is not available.

When a resource is created (whether via the AWS Management Console, AWS CLI or an API call via an AWS SDK), AWS will verify that the IAM entity associated with the credentials has permission to create the given resource. If so, the resource is created and is then **associated with the AWS Account**. It is *not* associated with the IAM entity that was used to create the resource. That is, there is no link between the resource and the user who created the resource.

AWS CloudTrail (if activated) records all API calls made to AWS, including *who* made the request and the details of what was requested (eg Launch an EC2 instance of a particular Instance Type in a given VPC). Therefore, it can be used to figure out **who requested the resource creation** (or termination, etc). Without this information, there is no link between the resource and the entity that created the resource.